# Select a random date | Watir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, watir

Given the following snippet of code how can I select a random date using Watir?

```
<div id="block-lb-search-search-widget" class="block-search-widget block-lb-search-search-widget search-widget">
<div class="row">
<div class="small-12 columns">
<div id="lb-search-widget-ajax-wrapper">
<form id="lb-search-search-widget-form" class="search-widget-element-count-6" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="/">
<div>
<ul class="search-fields clearfix">
<li class="charter-type-search clearfix">
<li class="destination-search where clearfix">
<li class="departure-search when clearfix">
<div class="icon-heading">
<div class="icon-search holiday-search-fields form-type-select form-item-date">
<select id="edit-date" class="form-select ajax-processed" name="date">
<option selected="selected" value="">Anytime</option>
<option value="2015-12">December 2015 (25)</option>
<option value="2016-01">January 2016 (26)</option>
<option value="2016-02">February 2016 (29)</option>
<option value="2016-03">March 2016 (30)</option>
<option value="2016-04">April 2016 (38)</option>
<option value="2016-05">May 2016 (37)</option>
<option value="2016-06">June 2016 (40)</option>
<option value="2016-07">July 2016 (39)</option>
<option value="2016-08">August 2016 (37)</option>
<option value="2016-09">September 2016 (33)</option>
<option value="2016-10">October 2016 (33)</option>
<option value="2016-11">November 2016 (28)</option>
<option value="2016-12">December 2016 (25)</option>
<option value="2017-01">January 2017 (21)</option>
<option value="2017-02">February 2017 (21)</option>
<option value="2017-03">March 2017 (21)</option>
<option value="2017-04">April 2017 (27)</option>
<option value="2017-05">May 2017 (27)</option>
<option value="2017-06">June 2017 (29)</option>
</select>
```

I have checked around but cannot find something suitable to use. Note sure if I am missing something obvious

Thanks

Comment: To be able to select any random date

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried selecting by index?

`browser.option(:index, rand(1..(number_of_entries - 1)))`

You would have to either know or calculate the number of entries, which should be easy enough.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. How would I implement this though? Sorry a little lost as I have not got so far into ruby.